Share UIView instance between class
I'm trying to share my UIView between some class for decode frame. For this, i've add sharedInstance method for get the instance from other class.
This method same not work and return an new instance, not the current.
My UIView class :
using namespace facebook::react;

@interface RTNViewStreamView () <RCTRTNViewStreamViewViewProtocol>

@end

@implementation RTNViewStreamView {
    UIView * _view;
}

+ (ComponentDescriptorProvider)componentDescriptorProvider
{
    return concreteComponentDescriptorProvider<RTNViewStreamViewComponentDescriptor>();
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    static const auto defaultProps = std::make_shared<const RTNViewStreamViewProps>();
    _props = defaultProps;

    _view = [[UIView alloc] init];
      NSLog(@"initWithFrame: %p", _view);

    self.contentView = _view;
  }

  return self;
}

+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static RTNViewStreamView *sharedClassA = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedClassA = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedClassA;
}

- (UIView *)getContentView {
    return self.contentView;
}

- (void)updateProps:(Props::Shared const &)props oldProps:(Props::Shared const &)oldProps
{
    const auto &oldViewProps = *std::static_pointer_cast<RTNViewStreamViewProps const>(_props);
    const auto &newViewProps = *std::static_pointer_cast<RTNViewStreamViewProps const>(props);

    if (oldViewProps.color != newViewProps.color) {
        NSString * colorToConvert = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: newViewProps.color.c_str()];
        [_view setBackgroundColor:[self hexStringToColor:colorToConvert]];
    }

    [super updateProps:props oldProps:oldProps];
}

Class<RCTComponentViewProtocol> RTNViewStreamViewCls(void)
{
    return RTNViewStreamView.class;
}

Then, from other class, i try this :
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        RTNViewStreamView *classA = [RTNViewStreamView sharedInstance];
        NSLog(@"init rtnstream: %p", classA.contentView);
        classA.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Not work
    }
    return self;
}

From logs, i see the initWithFrame method is re-run when i call the sharedInstance from other class :

I don't really understand why i can't retrieve my view instance? i need to use this instance to modify it somewhere else.
I'm on React-Native project, i write TurboModule with Fabric.

May be someone is setting contentView too?

What do you mean with the comment "Not work" when you set background color?

Looking at the results you printed, it seems that RTNViewStreamView was initialized twice. I'm not sure which instance you intend to use for editing. I don't understand why you don't let the ViewController hold the instance of RTNViewStreamView and instead use a singleton to hold it. In that case, the singleton will always end up holding only the most recently initialized instance.

To avoid initializing RTNViewStreamView twice, it is recommended that you create a separate singleton class to hold the instance of RTNViewStreamView.
